# POSTGRESQL - calling function with different times as input parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I was trying to call the function I created to fetch some data for particular time slot. Given below is a  script of my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(
    starttime timestamp with time zone,
    endtime timestamp with time zone)
RETURNS TABLE("Deviceid" integer, "AlertTime" timestamp with time zone)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0

AS $function$

 DECLARE 

r record;  

BEGIN 


SELECT "DeviceID" ,  "AlertTime" FROM my_table
WHERE "AlertTime" BETWEEN starttime AND endtime;

END;

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.my_function(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I am calling function with time '2016-12-15 00:00:01' to '2016-12-15 18:00:00' I am not getting any record. Even many records available for the time slot, I checked it by passing same time values for the query inside the function, its fetching data properly.

```
select * from my_function('2016-12-14 00:00:01','2016-12-15 18:00:00')
```

But when I am calling function with 2016-12-15 00:00:00' to '2016-12-15 18:00:00' I am able to get all records.

```
select *  from my_function('2016-12-14 00:00:00','2016-12-15 18:00:00')
```

Even I tried to change the input parameters to "character varying" and convert the input internally to time stamp even then it is not working.

Comment: your function is completely redundant!!

Comment: @ e4c5 : please tell me the relevant correction

Comment: your function merely returns the result of a select as a table. why on earth spend time and effort on things like this when you can just do the select?

Comment: @ e4c5: its just the sample i have posted, the original function is quiet complex and containing some temporary table. Please just tell me the solution for the time gap.

Comment: then post the real problem instead of sending everyone off on a while goose chase. and make sure to format your question properly

Comment: @ e4c5: due to some reasons i cann't post the original function

Comment: i m facing problem while passing the start time other than "00:00:00" ; even it is the deviation of single second it will not fetch the records

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is obvious, isn't it?

All the matching rows from `mytable` have `"AlertTime"` greater or equal than `2016-12-14 00:00:00` and less than `2016-12-14 00:00:01`.

Comment: I checked it by passing same time values for the query inside the function, its fetching data properly.

Comment: Then your real function must do something ifferent from the one in your question.